# Error "param is missing or the value is empty: article"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create an instance of "article" and the browser gives me an error

> param is missing or the value is empty: article

Here my article controller

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @article = Article.all
    end

    def new
          @article = Article.new
    end

    def create
        @article = Article.new(article_params)
     if @article.save
    redirect_to @article
     else
     render 'new'
  end
end

    def show
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body)
  end
end
```

how fix?

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates that the `article` parameter is missing or empty in the new form.  Go into the `project/views/new.html.erb` and make sure that you are actually passing `:article` to the url: `articles_path`.

```
<%= form_for :*article*, url:  articles_path do |f| %>
```

I had a typo in article (accidentally had typed articles) which produced exactly the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This is the method that raises the error.

```
def article_params
  params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body)
end
```

It means you are not passing such parameter to the controller. Make sure you have a form in the new/edit view and you are properly passing its values.

Comment: I understand that this method of error.But I think that's all true, and I have made one record it is save in the database and show on the page,  I decided to create another record and an error.Сuriously

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it worked for me:

```
def article_params
  params.require(:articles).permit(:title, :body)
end
```